# Migrate from 32bi to 64bit - OpenCV/MinGW/Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, opencv, crash, 64-bit

I'm working with opencv for couple of months under windows 32bit,with eclipse and mingw. After many hours, my program go through build, link without errors, but when start it crashes... my favorite "dont send" window.....

Source:

```
    #include <opencv.hpp>
    #include <windows.h>
    #include <iostream>

    using namespace std;
    using namespace cv;

    int main() {
       Mat img(Mat::zeros(100, 100, CV_8U));
       //imshow("window", img);
       cout << "hello world!" << endl;

       system("PAUSE");
       return 0;
    }
```

While imshow is comented, there is no problem, but when try to use imshow or waitKey, it compiles, but crashes ...

Build commands:

```
   g++ "-IW:\\Software\\opencv\\build\\include" "-IW:\\Software\\opencv\\build\\include\\opencv" "-IW:\\Software\\opencv\\build\\include\\opencv2" -O3 -g3 -Wall -Wextra -c -fmessage-length=0 -o "src\\HelloWorld.o" "..\\src\\HelloWorld.cpp" 

   g++ "-LW:\\Software\\opencv\\build\\x64\\mingw\\lib" -o HelloWorld.exe "src\\HelloWorld.o" -lopencv_calib3d246 -lopencv_contrib246 -lopencv_core246 -lopencv_features2d246 -lopencv_flann246 -lopencv_gpu246 -lopencv_highgui246 -lopencv_imgproc246 -lopencv_legacy246 -lopencv_ml246 -lopencv_nonfree246 -lopencv_objdetect246 -lopencv_photo246 -lopencv_stitching246 -lopencv_superres246 -lopencv_video246 -lopencv_videostab246
```

The system is: Win7 64bit, Eclipse CDT Kepler, Mingw. Before trat I was working on XP 32bit. Is there a possibility that the problem comes from the operating system ?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing each or both `-O3` and `-g3` compile options. they don't particularly play well with each other.

Also check if you've installed and linking against the 64-bit version of standard C++ library.

Try to remove the `system` command too. It invokes an external command, which can be problematic.

Also replace `cout` with `cerr`, which is unbuffered and so is better for outputting debug messages.

If the program still craches, comment each of the lines to single out the line which causes the problem for further tracking.

Comment: I remove -O3 and -g3 but without any result. If i comment imshow function it's working, but if i try to use imshow or waitKey(0) compiles, but crashes...  In the PATH variable i have W:\Software\opencv\build\x64\mingw\bin and W:\Software\mingw\mingw64\bin . I try to remove them and then the program is saying, that it can't find the DDL files - the DDLs are OK

Answer (score 0):

This question is a bit old now, but it might help someone else: I had the same problem. It just crashed without any informative error message. I ended up compiling OpenCV in 64bit mode using MingGW64 by myself and linking to those compiled libraries. Google around - there are tutorials on how to do that. Then it worked fine. My bet is that there is some compatibility issue between your C++ compiler/linker version and the one with which the OpenCV 64bit libraries were compiled.